# Channels within Structures?

Tags: structure, sections, channels

I have a site that requires the client to reorder their entries in each 'category' manually. Obviously structures are perfect for this but where I'm running into trouble is that the entries need to appear in multiple 'categories'.

Eg. Project One needs to appear in /projects and /selected-projects, both of which need the ability to be reordered via drag and drop functionality.

As far as I know using Craft's categories isn't an option as they can't be reordered so I'm trying to set this up with one channel that contains the entries and then using multiple structures and using the entries field so the client can add the entries they create in the channel to the structure.

Long story short, is it possible to display channels within structures?

Comment: To answer the question directly: no, you can't have channels within structures. But this does sound like a good problem to be solved by a plugin. One that allows you to drag-and-drop to select a priority for entries in a channel. I had a similar thing come up that needed this same functionality (haven't solved it yet though – sorry).

Comment: I did it in the end by adding a global for each 'sub category' based on the entries from that section if that helps anyone.

Answer (score 1):

I think you solved your own problem — by linking channel entries to structure entries using relationships (via the "Entries" field) you can display the same project in multiple locations. Seems like a perfect solution.

Comment: Almost, the final piece was actually adding globals based on the entries for each section that needed the reordering capability.

Comment: You lost me. But glad you solved it! ;)